# Java Error when uploading ESP32 script over the air (OTA) in Arduino IDE

Tags: upload, arduino-ide, esp32, ota

I'm trying to upload a script over the air to my esp32 device which is OTA enabled (i previously installed the software via Serial connection). The device shows up under ports, but when I select it and try to upload it to there Arduino IDE displays the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cc.arduino.packages.UploaderFactory.newUploader(UploaderFactory.java:45)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.getUploaderByPreferences(UploaderUtils.java:55)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:783)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:775)
    at processing.app.Editor$UploadHandler.run(Editor.java:2100)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`
```

I'm figuring it has something to do with Arduino IDE itself, as it was written in Java, right? But I don't know how to progress from here. Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it solved itself when I restarted Arduino IDE. I guess you have to do that before OTA updates..